# Mapping a jsp in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How do I map a jsp file in web folder (not in web-inf folder) in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/folder-holding-my-jsps/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: yes that is .i use the following code    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean> i want to map the jsp file in myproject/web directory.how can i do this?